# Multi-User seedbox in ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, bittorrent

Ok, so i need your help guys, i want to create a seedbox on my spare PC running ubuntu
its basically a HTPC, so i will be using it via remote in all probabilities.

so what i need to do is:

1. have usernames and passwords for login purposes, more than one.
2. be able to log into the torrent client and add/modify their torrent
3. logout

but i need to impose restrictions such as:

1. no one can access settings
2. no one can make changes to stuff added by some other ID

in short, what i aim for is making that machine into a multi user seedbox.
it has 2 GB of RAM and A TB of HDD space

any torrent client is welcome so long as it will do the job.
any idea on how we can do it?

Comment: Maybe Seedbox From Scratch is what you're looking for?
or TorrentFlux-b4rt... https://github.com/Notos/seedbox-from-scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to create a seedbox from scratch yourself, check out https://blog.slowb.ro/setup-a-mutli-user-seedbox-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you go with this script it will help ypi out a lot

The Seedbox From Scratch Script (Multi-user, quota, sabnzbd and Deluge)

http://www.torrent-invites.com/showthread.php?t=207635

You can create and delete seedbox users as you want !